# How match the last part of a line conditionally?

Tags: perl

I am very new to perl, currently I am using a very simple perl regex to print the last part of a line after the string "Lecture" reading from a file **1.txt**.

```
cat 1.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1 \n" while /Lecture\s+(\d+\w)/g;'
```

It works well but I need to add a simple condition to it:

First Preference is always print the characters after the string "Lecture".
If string "Lecture" is not found in a line, simply print the characters at the very end of line.

PS: It might occur that string "Lecture" doesn't have a space around it and throughout I used word character because it not necessarily would be a plain number, it can be alphanumeric .

Example
cat 1.txt

```
Some Topic 1 Lecture 001
Some Topic 2 Lecture 002
Topic 3 ( classroom Session ) Lecture2B
Practicals 07A
Submissions 10
Topic5Lecture4
```

Expected output:

```
001
002
2B
07A
10
4
```

I preferably want a solution which I can directly run in the cli/console. ( Just Like my original code - `cat 1.txt | perl code` ).
I don't want to execute a separate .pl file.

Comment: The expected output does not match the description "If string "Lecture" is not found in a line ,simply print the character at the very end of line.", for that the three characters "07A" should instead be the single character "A". This makes your question unclear.

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry for confusion , the veryinstance of a character starting number should be printed

Comment: I don't understand "the veryinstance of a character starting number". Maybe "number followed by a letter"? But that does not match e.g. "001".

Comment: Do you think that the details of your problem might be more consistently described by the text of your homework assigment? In that case please quote it as text directly here, instead of trying to summarise/rephrase.

Comment: Nvm i will remove that line , it might be confusing for some . Also i realised the fact that when there's only a single string and nd character , they do have spaces in between .. Appreciate you asking  for clarification , that line could cause confusion didn't struck me. I have updated the question

Comment: I get the impression that the end of the line, after the last occurence of whitespace or "Lecture" would do the trick.

Comment: Does this match what you need: `(?:Lecture)?([^\s]+)$` ? I.e. non-whitespace at the end of line, optionally preceeded by non-captured "Lecture".

Comment: I edited your question based on my understanding. Please double-check. I don't want to break it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
(?:\w*Lecture)?([^\s]+)$
```

Will capture (`(...)`) all (`+`) non-whitespace (`[^\s]`) at the end of line (`$`),
optionally (`?`) preceeded by non-captured(`(?:...)`) "Lecture",  even if there are other letters before (`\w*`).

It gets the desired output:

```
001
002
2B
07A
10
4
4
```

For the sample input:

```
Some Topic 1 Lecture 001
Some Topic 2 Lecture 002
Topic 3 ( classroom Session ) Lecture2B
Practicals 07A
Submissions 10
Topic5 Lecture4
Topic5Lecture4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering - i am running this command - cat 1.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1 \n" while /(?:Lecture)?([^\s]+)$/g;'      it gets the last line wrong for some reason and prints that line fully instead of just 4

Comment: I adapted to the changed input. I used the older sample input for my first version answer and then blindly copied the sample input after you edited it...

Comment: Hello Sir , Can you please read this - https://del.dog/aperyleppy.txt

Comment: Please turn that into a new dedicated question. Adressing users individually is not considered appropriate in the StackOverflow community. Your chances for help are better if everybody is helping, not only me. Also, where do you imagine I should put the answer? Make sure to add the desired output for the shown input. Also, the format of that input seems very different from the examples you provided here. The main difference being that the lines do not end with the part you want. (Sorry if I misunderstood that, especially when eding your question. I will assume you want to keep this as is now.)

Comment: Oops i thought current answer can be improved to cover a wider use case , if you recommend , i would definitely ask a new one ... thanks again

Comment: Sorry, but widening the use case and hoping for updated answers is considered "moving target question" and not appreciated. Go ahead, make a new question. I probably will not be able to resist answering. ;-)